# ViewPager ImageView not displaying in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, kotlin

I have a `ViewPager` containing 3 Fragments, one of which called `PostsFragment` contains a `RecyclerView`.  The `RecyclerView` holds 3 different view types depending on the type of post, either a photo, a video or an Album.  An album can contain any number of photos and videos and the idea is to be able to swipe between them, but I am only seeing my `TabLayout` dots indicating how many photos/videos there are, not the images themselves.

**CarouselVideoFragment.kt**

```
class CarouselVideoFragment() : Fragment() {

companion object Factory {
    fun newInstance() : CarouselVideoFragment = CarouselVideoFragment()
}

lateinit var carouselMedia : InstagramCarouselMedia
private val videoThumb : ImageView by bindView(R.id.carousel_photo)

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val bundle = arguments
    carouselMedia = bundle?.get("media") as InstagramCarouselMedia

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carousel_video, container, false)

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    videoThumb.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    Log.d("CAROUSEL", "URL: ${carouselMedia.image_versions2.candidates[0].url}")
    Picasso.with(context).load(carouselMedia.image_versions2.candidates[0].url).into(videoThumb)
    videoThumb.setOnClickListener { _ ->
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
        val data = Uri.parse(carouselMedia.video_versions[0].url)
        intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/*")
        ContextCompat.startActivity(context!!, intent, null)
    }

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}
}
```

**CarouselPhotoFragment.kt**

```
class CarouselPhotoFragment : Fragment() {

companion object Factory {
    fun newInstance() : CarouselPhotoFragment = CarouselPhotoFragment()
}

private val carouselPhoto : ImageView by bindView(R.id.carousel_photo)
lateinit var carouselMedia : InstagramCarouselMedia

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val args = arguments
    carouselMedia = args?.get("media") as InstagramCarouselMedia

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carousel_photo, container, false)

}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    carouselPhoto.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    Log.d("CAROUSEL", "URL: ${carouselMedia.image_versions2.candidates[0].url}")
    Picasso.with(context).load(carouselMedia.image_versions2.candidates[0].url).into(carouselPhoto)

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
}
}
```

**PostsListAdapter.kt**

```
class PostsListAdapter(private val postsFrag : PostsFragment,
                     private val items : List<InstagramTimelineFeedItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    when(holder.itemViewType) {
        1 -> {
            val viewHolder = holder as ViewHolder

            val item = items[position]

            if(item.media_or_ad != null) {

                viewHolder.username.text = item.media_or_ad.user.username
                Picasso.with(postsFrag.activity).load(item.media_or_ad.user.profile_pic_url).noFade().into(viewHolder.profilePic)
                Picasso.with(postsFrag.activity).load(item.media_or_ad.image_versions2.candidates[0].url).into(viewHolder.postImage)

                if(item.media_or_ad.caption != null) {

                    viewHolder.postCaption.text = item.media_or_ad.caption.get("text") as String

                }

            }
        }
        2 -> {
            val viewHolder = holder as ViewHolderVideo

            val item = items[position]

            if(item.media_or_ad != null) {

                viewHolder.username.text = item.media_or_ad.user.username
                Picasso.with(postsFrag.activity).load(item.media_or_ad.user.profile_pic_url).noFade().into(viewHolder.profilePic)
                Picasso.with(postsFrag.activity).load(item.media_or_ad.image_versions2.candidates[0].url).into(viewHolder.postVideoThumb)

                viewHolder.postVideoThumb.setOnClickListener { _ ->
                    val intent = Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                    val data = Uri.parse(item.media_or_ad.video_versions[0].url)
                    intent.setDataAndType(data, "video/*")
                    startActivity(postsFrag.context!!, intent, null)
                }

                if(item.media_or_ad.caption != null) {

                    viewHolder.postCaption.text = item.media_or_ad.caption.get("text") as String

                }

            }
        }
        else -> {
            // Album type
            val viewHolder = holder as ViewHolderCarousel
            val item = items[position]

            viewHolder.username.text = item.media_or_ad.user.username
            Picasso.with(postsFrag.activity).load(item.media_or_ad.user.profile_pic_url).noFade().into(viewHolder.profilePic)

            val adapter = CarouselAdapter(postsFrag.childFragmentManager, item.media_or_ad.carousel_media)
            viewHolder.viewPager.adapter = adapter
            viewHolder.tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewHolder.viewPager)

            viewHolder.caption.text = item.media_or_ad.caption.get("text").toString()
        }
    }

}

override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
    val item = items[position]
    if(item.media_or_ad == null)
        return 5
    return item.media_or_ad.media_type
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    when(viewType) {
        1 -> return ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(postsFrag.activity).inflate(R.layout.post_list_item, parent, false))
        2 -> return ViewHolderVideo(LayoutInflater.from(postsFrag.activity).inflate(R.layout.post_list_item_video, parent, false))
        else -> {
            return ViewHolderCarousel(LayoutInflater.from(postsFrag.activity).inflate(R.layout.post_list_item_carousel, parent, false))
        }
    }
}

inner class CarouselAdapter(fm: FragmentManager,
                      val carouselMedia : List<InstagramCarouselMedia>) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fm) {

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return carouselMedia.size
    }

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {

        Log.d("ADAPTER", "Type: ${carouselMedia[position].media_type}")

        if(carouselMedia[position].media_type == 1) {
            val frag = CarouselVideoFragment.newInstance()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putSerializable("media", carouselMedia[position])
            frag.arguments = args
            return frag
        } else if(carouselMedia[position].media_type == 2) {
            val frag = CarouselVideoFragment.newInstance()
            val args = Bundle()
            args.putSerializable("media", carouselMedia[position])
            frag.arguments = args
            return frag
        }

        return Fragment()

    }
}

class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val profilePic : CircleImageView by bindView(R.id.profile_image)
    val username : TextView by bindView(R.id.username)
    val postImage : ImageView by bindView(R.id.post_image)
    val postCaption : TextView by bindView(R.id.post_caption)

}

class ViewHolderVideo(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val profilePic : CircleImageView by bindView(R.id.profile_image)
    val username : TextView by bindView(R.id.username)
    val postCaption : TextView by bindView(R.id.post_caption)
    val postVideoThumb : ImageView by bindView(R.id.video_thumb)

}

class ViewHolderCarousel(itemView : View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

    val profilePic : CircleImageView by bindView(R.id.profile_image)
    val username : TextView by bindView(R.id.username)
    val viewPager : ViewPager by bindView(R.id.carousel_viewpager)
    val tabs : TabLayout by bindView(R.id.carousel_tabs)
    val caption : TextView by bindView(R.id.post_caption)

}
}
```

**post_list_item_carousel.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="12dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/carousel_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabGravity="center"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/carousel_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/post_caption"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_carousel_video.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/carousel_photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**fragment_carousel_photo.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/carousel_photo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/play_button"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I have right now:

[image: The 3 dots should have an image (inside a viewpager) above them]

Comment: Instead of setting height as wrap_content to your image_view in  `fragment_carousel_video.xml` try to add some height first. Add check is it showing image now or not

Comment: I'm still just seeing the dots after adding 200dp of height.  Maybe the `ViewPager` itself is not being displayed?

Comment: Hey i have one question, in `PostsListAdapter.kt` at `getItem()` in both `media_types` you are showing `CarouselVideoFragment` why ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, the problem still persists after fixing

Comment: Hey try to add some `height` to `carousel_viewpager`. And again a question why you are using a `tablayout` ?

Comment: I'm using it because I want to show how many images/videos there are in an album.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162446/discussion-between-heisen-berg-and-charlie-niekirk).